# when an area of trapezoid ABCD reaches maximum , sum of two length of diagonal =?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, area

When an area of trapezoid ABCD reaches maximum , what is length  of sum two diagonal ?

[image: trapezoid]

Comment: Which of the points $A,B,C,D$ can you adjust to maximize the area?

Comment: It looks since the 30 degrees is written in, that only B and C are allowed to move over the semicircle. But the OP should make this clear in the question, and also state what seems to be so that the figure is a semicircle atop the diagonal of the circle with one endpoint being D.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Suppose we only move point $B$ at first. At the maximum area, point $B$ must be at the midpoint of arc $ABC$ since the trapezoid area is the sum of areas of triangle $ACD$ (which is fixed for now) and triangle $ACB$ whose area is 1/2 times the base $AC$ times the altitude from vertex $B$ over side $AC,$ and that is the most when $B$ is at the midpoint of arc $ABC$ since the midpoint of the arc is the furthest away from the base when measured vertically to the base.

By a similar argument, if we only move point $C$ we find it must be at the midpoint of arc $BCD$ when the trapezoid area is maximal. Combining these two facts we see that the points $A,B,C,D$ must, at the maximal trapezoid area, be equally spaced along the arc $ABCD.$ Now since the coordinates of $A,D$ can be found, some trig can get the coordinates of $B,C$ also, and from there one can compute the lengths of the two diagonals, hence their sum.